# HTML PHP JS select choose different option to show different checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a form which includes select. Base on the different option, different checkboxes will be shown for further choice.

I used to hide and show JS code, but it does not work for the user to choose all checkboxes(User can choose both ball game and water game ). How can I avoid to let the user choose all checkboxes?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sort').change(function(){
    $('.sort2').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).load();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form " method="post" id="s-form"> 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sort">Sort</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sort">
                <option value="ball">Ball game</option>
                <option value="water">Water game</option>
            </select>
     </div>
</form>
  
    <div class="row" id="ball" class="sort2 ball" style="display: none">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="football" > Football
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="basketball" > Basketball
    </div>
  
    <div class="row" id="water" class="sort2 water" style="display: none">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="swimming" checked="checked"> Swimming
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="diving" > Diving
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain your questions? it doesn't make sense what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sort').change(function(){
    $('.sort2').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form " method="post" id="s-form"> 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sort">Sort</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sort">
                <option value="ball">Ball game</option>
                <option value="water">Water game</option>
            </select>
     </div>
</form>
  
    <div class="row sort2 ball" id="ball" style="display: none">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="football" > Football
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="basketball" > Basketball
    </div>
  
    <div class="row sort2 water" id="water"  style="display: none">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="swimming" checked="checked"> Swimming
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="diving" > Diving
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sort').change(function(){
    //$('.sort2').hide();
    $('select option').each(function(){
      $('#' + $(this).val()).hide();
    });
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form " method="post" id="s-form"> 
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sort">Sort</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sort">
                <option value="ball">Ball game</option>
                <option value="water">Water game</option>
            </select>
     </div>
</form>
  
    <div class="row" id="ball" class="sort2 ball" style="display: none">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="football" > Football
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="basketball" > Basketball
    </div>
  
    <div class="row" id="water" class="sort2 water" style="display: none">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="swimming" checked="checked"> Swimming
        <input type="checkbox" name="sort2" value="diving" > Diving
    </div>
```

Comment: @LamSam, Please try it.

Answer (score -1):

remove `style="display: none"` 
from div tag 
and replace `.load()` function to `.show()`

```
$(function() {
  $('.sort2').hide();
  $('#sort').change(function(){
    $('.sort2').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```